# Expand / Show and hide div element in a listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see, is this a list view and my mission is when you click on an element / div then the div with the images expand / show. Now that is easy, even for a backend developer, but I would like to:
1. when I click again on the same element, then the element will hide. 
2. When I click on another element, then the element that is already expand will hide and the other element that I click on, will expand / show. 
I need Script and CSS for this please.

```
<div class="row">
                @foreach(var post in CurrentPage.Children) 
                {
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="content equal" onclick="showhide()">
                            <a href="@post.Url">
                                <div class="date">@post.CreateDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
                                <h2>@post.Name</h2>     
                                <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(post.Introduction, 240, true)</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="images(-expand)">
                            <img src="@post.Image" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
```

Comment: what's your `showhide()` doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows.

```js
$('.content.equal').click(function() {
  $('.content.equal').not(this).next().slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});

$('.content.equal a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.images {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="content equal">
    <a href="@post.Url">
      <div class="date">12-01-2017</div>
      <h2>Name1</h2>
      <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(post.Introduction, 240, true)</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="content equal">
    <a href="@post.Url">
      <div class="date">12-01-2017</div>
      <h2>Name1</h2>
      <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(post.Introduction, 240, true)</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="content equal">
    <a href="@post.Url">
      <div class="date">12-01-2017</div>
      <h2>Name1</h2>
      <p>@Umbraco.Truncate(post.Introduction, 240, true)</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Harish Kommuri , it seems to work perfectly.